# Android Execution failed for task app.compileDebugKotlin when firebase is used

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication, kotlin

Getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

As soon as I add this line of code to the app

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

`Dependency` is added to gradle app module

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

Any idea what's causing this error?

**EDIT**

```
: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbql
```

but I do have it

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.21.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

Comment: did you add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` in your project level gradle file?

Comment: Anything useful in the log?

Comment: yes google services is added, I installed firebase through android tools

Comment: Please tell me how you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Project gradle**

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'

        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }


    **app gradle**

    dependencies {      
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    }

**Please add this below dependencies and make sure firebase and play-services versions should be same.**

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have except `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`, adding that causes new errors complaining about using different/conflicting version of google play

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

Comment: Please try my latest answer.